# How to detect if DownloadString Failed?

Tags: vb.net, ip, try-catch, detection, downloadstring

I'm trying to put my External IP in a Label, so I'm downloading the result based on a site, but the moment I change my IP via VPN, the application crashes, I believe it's because it does not check if it's getting the string down, that he tried.

On form load...

```
 If Label1.Text = LastIp Then

      Try

      Dim wc As New WebClient
      Label1.Text = wc.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/")

      If you can not then

      Label.Text = "Failed to get IP"

      End if

 End If
```

**Form...**

[image]

Comment: Use a [**`Try/Catch` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement). Also if you could tell us the error you're getting that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a callback and specify the path to the file:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf DownloadStringComplete
wc.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://icanhazip.com/myfile.txt", UriKind.Absolute))

Private Sub DownloadStringComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)

If Not IsNothing(e.Error) Then
    Label1.Text = e.Error.Message
ElseIf e.Cancelled Then
    Label1.Text = "canceled"
Else
    Label1.Text = e.Result
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't have file, it's only the site.

Comment: If you just want the default page just use "http://icanhazip.com" without a file name or better yet specify the page name like: "http://icanhazip.com/default.html". If you want to download the whole site that is another subject.

Comment: Don't use `If Not IsNothing(e.Error) Then`, that's VB6-style code. Use `If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then` instead.